# How to speed up Kafka while pushing data into it after fetching the same from MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-kafka

I am fetching data from MongoDB and putting it into Kafka. 357 responses/second is the rate at which fetching and publishing are done.

How can I improve the fetching from MongoDB:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from kafka.errors import KafkaError
import json
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import sys

try:
  client = MongoClient('my_uri')
  db = client["xxx-dev"]
except Exception as e:
    print e
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])
producer = KafkaProducer(retries=5)
id = 1
for response in db.Response.find():
    try:        
        future = producer.send('collect-production-response', bytes(response))
    except Exception as e:
        print e
    id  += 1
    if(id >= 100000):
        print "Done 100k"
        producer.flush()
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: Have you tried profiling your code and see where it spends most of its time?

Comment: I would suggest using Debezium Mongo Connector

Comment: why this `json.dumps(response, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)` and this `producer = KafkaProducer(retries=5)` ? I think you can set the retry where you init the producer, only once. Formatting the json has a cost; not sure why you flush every record, you can move it out of the loop

Comment: @Paizo
I removed the _jsonification_ , producer.flush() was moved out of the loop and retires thing was at the top, out of the loop.

The speed is way better but not as per Kafka's standards.
Now, it took 90 seconds to fetch and store 10000 records.
What further improvisation can I do?

Comment: you should check what can be improved, is the fetching from the database slow? You can also split the work with multiple producers. If you want to find out what could be the speed with your setup you can skip the database part and send a predefined message

Comment: @Paizo
Fetching from db takes 2 mins 30 secs and fetching+publishing takes 4 mins 10 secs